# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)≅\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**The Problem**: Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$.

The same question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2748999/506332); but the answers are more confusing than helpful.

**My Attempt**: Let $I=(2, x^3+1)$. By the *Third Isomorphism Theorem*, we have $(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2))/(I/(2))\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$. Now, if we can show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and $I/(2)\cong(x^3+1)$ (the last "$(x^3+1)$" is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$), then we'd be done; but these two isomorphisms aren't actually all that easy to show. My question is: is there a better way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One approach is to think about the kernel of the surjection $\mathbb Z[x]\to\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^3+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$f:\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \frac{\mathbb{Z_2}[x]}{(x^3+1)}$ such that $f(p) =\bar{p}+(x^3+1) $ where $\bar{p}$ denotes p in $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$

Clearly, $f$ is a ring homomorphism.
Now, We have to observe kernel of $f$.

Let, $g \in kerf$
Then, $\bar{g} \in (x^3+1) $
hence, $\bar{g} =\bar{h}(x^3+1)$

Now, $g=\bar{g} + 2q$,
$ g= \bar{h}(x^3+1) +2q$,
$ g \in (2,x^3+1). $
Hence, $kerf \subseteq (2,x^3+1) $.
Conversely ,
If $q \in (2,x^3+1) $
Then, $f(q) =(x^3+1)$ which is additive identity of codomain ring.

The map is onto by definition .

By 1st isomorphism theorem,
$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2,x^3+1)} \cong $ $\frac{\mathbb{Z_2}[x]}{(x^3+1)}$

Answer (score 0):

One alternative proof.

Consider a coset-element $p(x)+(2,x^3+1)$ of the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$, where $p(x)∈\Bbb{Z}[x]$. If $p(x)$ has a term with even coefficient, then this term belongs to the ideal $(2,x^3+1)$, so that it vanishes from $p(x)+(2,x^3+1)$. If $p(x)$ has a term with odd coefficient, then this odd coefficient can be written as $2k+1$ with $k∈\Bbb{Z}$, hence the term can be written as a sum of two terms, one of which has even coefficient hence belongs to the ideal $(2,x^3+1)$ hence vanishes from $p(x)+(2,x^3+1)$, and the other has coefficient $1$. Thus, *all nonzero terms* of a coset-element $p(x)+(2,x^3+1)$ of the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$ *have coefficient* **$1$**, hence $p(x)+(2,x^3+1)$ is actually a polynomial with coefficients from $\Bbb{Z}_2$, so that it can be *bijectively mapped with a copy of itself* in the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(2,x^3+1)$; note here that the ring $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ indeed has an ideal $(2,x^3+1)=(0,x^3+1)=(x^3+1)$. This *bijection* $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)↔\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(2,x^3+1)$ or, which is the same, $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)↔\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$ defines a *natural isomorphism* between these quotient rings because in fact *it maps each element to itself*. 
**Thus**, $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)≅\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$.